# Compilation error with boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings

Tags: c++, xml, boost, boost-propertytree

In order to pretty print my XML output with [boost::property_tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/), I wrote the following code:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string filename = "test.xml";
    boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
    pt.put("some.path.value", "hello");

    boost::property_tree::xml_writer_settings<char> settings('\t', 1);
    write_xml(filename, pt, settings);
}
```

Unfortunately I have this error and I can't find any information about it:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp:38:19: error: type 'char' cannot be used prior to '::' because it has no members
    typedef typename Str::value_type Ch;
                     ^
```

Any idea?

Comment: [This document](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_writer_settings.hpp) **may** help you, but I'm not sure

Comment: this is the header I'm using

Comment: _Next time_: Please include relevant code in the question, so we can ace the answer, instead of drawing out "thanks but..." in the comments :)

Comment: Yes I will add it right now

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd use the helper function

```
std::ofstream file("test.xml");

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;    
pt.put("some.value", "test");

boost::property_tree::write_xml(
   file, pt,
   boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>('\t', 1));
```

Comment: It works but how can I use it with write_xml? When writing `write_xml(filename, pt, boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>('\t', 1))` I have the following error: `no matching function for call to 'write_xml`

Comment: @MartinDelille You need to pass a stream, not a filename. The documentation is patient :) http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/write_xml_idp113303904.html (also funny you truncated the message because now I'm having to guess what the types of `filename` and `pt` are).

Comment: There is an issue with changing from `<char> to <std::string>` it only works if you are building on a 64bit, otherwise if you are building on 32bit and try to use <std::string> then you will get above described error, however if you are building on 64bit you will not get the error -- this assuming that you used a stream and not filename

Comment: @serup that makes little sense. It seems like you may be conflating character encoding and build architecture.

Comment: @sehe, I agree it makes little sense, none the less it is the fact - try it out